# looping thru array of images from API not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im currently trying to display a carousel of images fetched from the API.

the image url is in an array.

so i tried to do this.

```
async function fetchData(){
    let response = await axios.get(`---API---`);
    let data =  await response.data.data
    setresult(data)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();

    },[])

const putih =()=> {
    setToCart(result[0])
    return (
      <Carousel interval={null} >
        {result[0]?.image?.map((images, i)=>
          
            <Carousel.Item key={i}>
              <LazyLoadImage effect="blur" 
              className="d-block w-100"
              src={`https://ecgobikeid.com/${images}`}
             
              />
            </Carousel.Item>
        )
        }
      </Carousel>
    )}
  const hitam =() => {
    setToCart(result[1])
    return (
      <Carousel interval={null} >
         {result[1]?.image?.map((images)=>{
          return(
            <Carousel.Item>
              <LazyLoadImage effect="blur" 
              className="d-block w-100"
              src={`https://ecgobikeid.com/${images}`}
              alt="First slide"
            />
            </Carousel.Item>
          )
        })}
       </Carousel>
    )}
  const merah =() => {
    setToCart(result[2])
    return (
      <Carousel interval={null} >
        {result[2]?.image?.map((images)=>{
          return(
            <Carousel.Item>
              <LazyLoadImage effect="blur" 
              className="d-block w-100"
              src={`https://ecgobikeid.com/${images}`}
              alt="First slide"
            />
            </Carousel.Item>
          )
        })}
      </Carousel>
    )}
```

`const [selected, setSelected] = useState(putih)`

and then render the `{selected}` state in the main component.

but nothing in the carousel immidiately after page load. but if i click a button changing the `selected` state then the image showing up.

the data from the API is already fetched, and the default `selected` state is already declared.

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Are you sure, that the `selected` state is set after the images have been loaded? It seems to me like you use an API Response that is not yet loaded when the page initally renders.

Comment: i edited my code above, so im assuming the API response is loaded as soon as the page renders @ioasjfopas